# Installing software while logged into admin vs standard user - what difference does it make?

Tags: install, accounts

What difference does it make which account you're logged into when you perform an installation? I'm running 10.8

Just curious.

Comment: What do you mean "avoiding a password prompt"? Even when logged in as an admin you still have to type your password to install software. It's the system's way of letting you know that something's trying to make changes, in case it was actually malicious software trying to install itself in the background.

Comment: @tubedogg Ah, I wasn't sure about that, as it's been a while since I did any installing while logged in as an admin. I'll cut that bit out of the question.

Comment: There is a difference with the password prompt; but, it is subtle.  If you are logged in as an admin user, the username portion of the password prompt will already be filled out.  (It is still changeable).  If you are logged in as a non-admin user, then the username and password will both be blank.